# UIScrollView on tvOS

Tags: uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer, uiscrollviewdelegate, uipinchgesturerecognizer, tvos

The question is very simple, how to enable scroll and zoom inside a UIScrollView in tvOS?

I tried the same initializer code from iOS and returned the scrollview for the **focusedView** var, but nothing happens when i touch the remote.

Also, i tried to add another custom **UIPanGestureRecognizer** to the scrollview and actually it works, but i don't want to handle the pan with custom code, just use the same pan behavior like iOS.

Let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can configure the scroll view's built-in pan gesture to recognize touches on the Siri Remote. It doesn't do that automatically, because normally scroll views on tvOS aren't scrolled directly by touches: they're scrolled automatically as focus moves between views within the scroll view.

If you really want the scroll view to move directly from touches, you'll need to add `UITouchTypeIndirect` to the `allowedTouchTypes` of the scroll view's `panGestureRecognizer`:

```
scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = @[ @(UITouchTypeIndirect) ];
```

You'll also need to make sure that either the scroll view itself is the focused view, or is a parent of the focused view, since all touches from the remote will start at the center of the focused view: you need to make sure the scroll view is getting hit-tested for the events to work.

Zooming won't work, because the Siri Remote can only recognize one touch at a time, so you can't do a pinch gesture on it.

Comment: But you can't zoom only on simulator? What about the real Apple Remote?

Comment: Just a note on zoom. You can get it to work but you'll have to use a different gesture e.g a double tap to zoom in and a double tap to zoom out on the scrollview.

Comment: But how to actually make the scroll view focused? I have another scroll view that has items with focus and I need to switch between these scroll views.

Comment: Ok answering to myself: simply override method canBecomeFocused

Comment: I have this working but I noticed that the scrolling is unreliable, some of my gestures don't trigger a response. I have the feeling that some other  recognizer is processing touches before, and these get delayed or discarded before reaching the pan recognizer, but don't know how to avoid that.

Comment: Is there any way to leave the focus again? For instance when the scrollview is scrolled to top and there is a tabbar above it? UITextView does this automatically but UIScrollView won't.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 version (from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41000183/945247)

```
scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value:UITouchType.indirect.rawValue)]
```