# UITextView not Scrolling in tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, tvos, apple-tv

I have a `UITextView` in my TV app, when i try to make it focusable then the UI is not making it focusable and i am unable to scroll it. I read some questions about it and some says that its a known issue and we should use storyboards. Actually i am using storyboards but still unable to get this to work. I have also tried to make it `selectable`, `scrollEnabled` and `userInteractionEnabled` and then finally also tried this line of code but none of them is working.

```
descriptionLbl.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UITouchType.Direct.rawValue)]
```

I also tried to print `bounds` abd `contentSize` of the `UITextView` and here is the log

```
Content Size (740.0, 914.0)
Bounds (25.0, 0.0, 740.0, 561.0)
```

Here is my code can some body help me

```
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLbl: UITextView!
var currentModel : Model?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    descriptionLbl.selectable = true
    descriptionLbl.scrollEnabled = true
    descriptionLbl.userInteractionEnabled = true


    descriptionLbl.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UITouchType.Direct.rawValue)]


    descriptionLbl.text = (currentModel?.description)! + (currentModel?.description)! + (currentModel?.description)!
    descriptionLbl?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: -25.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0);


}
```

i guess i should not be doing these many tricks but it is not working in any way. The focus is actually coming to `UITextView` but it does not scroll. Any ideas?

Comment: (2023) There seems to be a very odd bug/behavior that it Just Don't Work if you set them on storyboard, gotta set in code.  Wild.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you want Indirect, not Direct touches. Here is how I set up my focusable, scrollable UITextView:

```
self.selectable = YES;
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = @[@(UITouchTypeIndirect)];
```

Comment: by making it userInteractionEnabled, it's automatically focusable

Answer (score 8):

For Swift 5, this is what worked for me:

```
    textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
    textView.isScrollEnabled = true;
    textView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true;
    textView.bounces = true;
    textView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouch.TouchType.indirect.rawValue)]
```

Comment: You just need to use: `view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` and
    `view.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouch.TouchType.indirect.rawValue)]`

Comment: (2023) There seems to be a very odd bug/behavior that it Just Don't Work if you set them on storyboard, gotta set in code.  Wild.

Comment: @DiogoT very surprisingly it DID NOT work for me unless I used, wait for it, the bounces clause.  WTH.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what worked for me, in Swift 2.1:

```
myTextView.userInteractionEnabled = true
myTextView.selectable = true
myTextView.scrollEnabled = true
myTextView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [UITouchType.Indirect.rawValue]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `scrollEnabled` seems to be true by default, so maybe redundant

Answer (score 6):

Here's what worked for me in Swift 3.0.1, based on the previous answers:

- I had to subclass `UITextView` to override `canBecomeFocused` to return `true`
- I had to set `panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouchType.indirect.rawValue)]`
- I had to set `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` in code - setting it in Interface Builder didn't seem sufficient
- I had to check "Scrolling Enabled" in Interface builder (setting `isScrollEnabled = true` in code would also work

A few other niceties I found:

- `bounces = true` made scrolling feel more natural (had to be set in code; IB setting not respected)
- `showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true` had to be set in code; IB setting not respected
- Overriding `didUpdateFocus(in:with:)` to change the background color to visually indicate the focus.

Comment: "Cannot override mutable property with read-only property 'isScrollEnabled'"

Comment: It is giving the above error while setting the property isScrollEnabled in latest swift 3 and xcode versions.

Comment: you dont need to use "canBecomeFocused to return true" but still this is a big help

Answer (score 0):

If you use objective-C to do this, It would be very sample：

```
    _textView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = @[@(UITouchTypeIndirect)];
    _textView.selectable = YES;
    _textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    _textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Above these are enough, However, If you use swift to do this, It doesn't work.

Comment: In swift, you can set:           
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        
   
 textView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouch.TouchType.indirect.rawValue)]